# Иконка расширения только на страницах из списка

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Доброго времени суток.
Как отображать иконку расширения только на страницах из списка?
Желательно через манифест, к сожалению поиск не помог.

Comment: можете уточнить вопрос - не догоняю что вам надо. какой список и где именно иконка нужна. Или вы имеете в виду адресную панель справа или панель инструментов???

Comment: P.S. Расширение абсолютно ничего не делает на настоящее время. Просто пустой шаблон.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

на этот случай существует pageAction и отображаться он будет в адресной строке.

так как хотите вы вряд ли получиться, потому что есть функция добавления, но нет функции удаления иконки с панели. остается манипуляция со свойствами enable/disable (хотя эти свойства может и дадут требуемый эффект, не проверял, если чесно)

в манифесте:

```
"browser_action": {
"default_title": "",
"default_icon": "images/icon52x52.png"
},
"permissions": ["tabs","activeTab"]
```

в background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(id,info,tab){
var re = new RegExp(/^http\:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:sezn)|(?:hashcode)\.ru.*/i);

/*если вкладка с нужным адресом, то делаем активной иконку, в противном случае неактивной*/
if (re.test(tab.url)) chrome.browserAction.enable(id); else chrome.browserAction.disable(id);
})
```

можно добавить процедуру по замене иконке или сплошной заливки цветом, см: chrome.browserAction.setTitle('title' : 'text'), chrome.browserAction.setIcon({'path': ''}), chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: [/*190, 190, 190, 230*/]}), getBadgeBackgroundColor и т.д.

если все решите воспользоваться pageAction, то в манифесте:

```
"permissions": ["tabs","activeTab"],
"page_action": {
  "default_icon": "images/icon52x52.png",
  "default_title": "ваш заголовок",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"/*попуп вашей иконки если требуется*/
}
```

в background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(id,info,tab){
  var re = new RegExp(/^http\:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:sezn)|(?:hashcode)\.ru.*/i);
  if (re.test(tab.url)) chrome.pageAction.show(id);

  /*если требуется свой обработчик клика по иконке*/
  //chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){alert('hello world!');})
  /*то убираем комменты выше, и убираем с манифеста "default_popup"*/

  /*если вкладка с нужным адресом, то делаем видимой иконку, в противном случае невидимой*/
if (re.test(tab.url)) chrome.pageAction.show(id); else chrome.pageAction.hide(id);
});
```

Comment: @slavutich, спасибо. Решил использовать `page_actions`, что идеологически верно:  

> **Советы**  
> Для лучшего визуального воздействия, соблюдайте следующие правила:
>   
> - Используйте `page_actions` для функций, которые используются лишь на некоторых страницах  
> - Не используйте `page_actions` для функций, которые используются для большинства страниц. Используйте `browser_actions`.  
> - Не надо постоянно анимировать значок. Это просто раздражает.  

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html